# KQL query to take a table with a field with array data and break out each value in the array

Tags: kql

I have a table like this:

Table1

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ["1","2","8"] |
| 2 | ["2","3","7"] |

What I would like to do is to break that table out into a list like:

| Column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 8 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 7 |

I haven't been able to get the right query to split the column 2 and pair this with the original column1 values.

How would I do that? Ta Steve

Comment: What is the type of Column2? an array? a string? Why are those integers qualified?

Answer (score 0):

```
datatable(Column1:int, Column2:dynamic)
[
   ,1, dynamic(["1","2","8"])
   ,2, dynamic(["2","3","7"])
]
| mv-expand Column2
```

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 8 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 7 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA0tJLAHCpJxUDef8nNLcPEOrzLwSHQUIx8gqpTIvMTczWZOXK5qXS0FBQcdQRwEqphGtZKiko2QExBZKsZoQaSNkaZCUMRCbg6VjeblqFHLLdFMrChLzUmA2AACqhQXfgAAAAA==)

Comment: Hi David, thank you. Column 2 is a system.object array. mv-expand has done the trick. Thanks heaps, I wasn't familiar with mv-expand.